# HashMap with override equals and hashCode not working

Tags: java, hashmap

Sorry ... about this silly/stupid question, guys:

Why aren't `equals()` and `hashCode()` being applied?

Currently they are only working as I expected for `HashSet`.

**UPDATE**

EVEN key value 5 is repeated but it doesn't call equals and hashCode.

I want to apply it also on Value.

As just like HashSet calls equal and hashCode in this example, why hashMap is not being called equals and hashCode even if for key.

**UPDATE2 - ANSWER**

HashMap's key(class->HashCode, equals) would be called.
Thank you All.
I was little bit confused on this.
:)

```
    public class Employee {

        int id;
        String name; 
        int phone;

        public Employee(int id, String name, int phone) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.phone = phone;
        }    
    // Getter Setter

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {

            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Employee other = (Employee) obj;
            System.out.println("Employee -  equals" + other.getPhone());
            if (this.id != other.id) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.phone != other.phone) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            System.out.println("Employee -  hashCode" );
            int hash = 3;
            hash = 67 * hash + this.id;
            hash = 67 * hash + (this.name != null ? this.name.hashCode() : 0);
            hash = 67 * hash + this.phone;
            return hash;
        }
    }

____________________________________________________________________________________

public class MapClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer,Employee> map = new HashMap<Integer,Employee>();
        map.put(1, new Employee(1, "emp", 981));
        map.put(2, new Employee(2, "emp2", 982));
        map.put(3, new Employee(3, "emp3", 983));
        map.put(4, new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));
        map.put(5, new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));
       **//UPDATE**
        map.put(5, new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));            

        System.out.println("Finish Map" + map.size());
        Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<Employee>();

        set.add(new Employee(1, "emp", 981));
        set.add(new Employee(2, "emp2", 982));
        set.add(new Employee(2, "emp2", 982));
        set.add(new Employee(3, "emp3", 983));
        set.add(new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));
        set.add(new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));

        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT IS

```
Finish Map5
Employee -  hashCode
Employee -  hashCode
Employee -  hashCode
Employee -  equals982
Employee -  equals982
Employee -  hashCode
Employee -  hashCode
Employee -  hashCode
Employee -  equals984
Employee -  equals984
4
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Remember that in HashMap, the keys is hashed, not the value

Comment: how would i call hascode & equals for hashMap

Comment: The Map calls the equals and hashCode methods, and it is doing that -- for the Integer key! If you want the Map to check Employee hashCode and/or equals then Employee must be the Key not the Value.

Comment: why hashMap(equals & hascode) is not being called even if for key is repeated.

Comment: Glad you've got it figured out! 1+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> EVEN key value 5 is repeated but it doesn't call equals and hashCode

Yes it does call hashCode, on the key, the Integer.

> I want to apply it also on Value

Dose of reality: Java HashMaps don't work that way. They check the key only for duplicates, not the value, and this is as it should be.

If you want Employee's hash to be checked in the Map, then it *must* be the key. Period.

Another possible solution is to download one of the multimaps that are available.

**Edit**  to see that it's calling hashCode and equals, change your Map's key type to something like so:

```
class MyInt {
   private Integer i;

   public MyInt(Integer i) {
      this.i = i;
   }

   public Integer getI() {
      return i;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      System.out.println("MyInt HashCode: " + i.hashCode());
     return i.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      System.out.printf("MyInt equals: [%s, %s]%n", i, obj);
      if (this == obj)
         return true;
      if (obj == null)
         return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
         return false;
      MyInt other = (MyInt) obj;
      if (i == null) {
         if (other.i != null)
            return false;
      } else if (!i.equals(other.i))
         return false;
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return i.toString();
   }

}
```

Then fill your Map like so:

```
   Map<MyInt,Employee> map = new HashMap<MyInt,Employee>();
   map.put(new MyInt(1), new Employee(1, "emp", 981));
   map.put(new MyInt(2), new Employee(2, "emp2", 982));
   map.put(new MyInt(3), new Employee(3, "emp3", 983));
   map.put(new MyInt(4), new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));
   map.put(new MyInt(5), new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));
   map.put(new MyInt(5), new Employee(4, "emp4", 984));
```

and you'll see:

```
MyInt HashCode: 1
MyInt HashCode: 2
MyInt HashCode: 3
MyInt HashCode: 4
MyInt HashCode: 5
MyInt HashCode: 5
MyInt equals: [5, 5]
```

Comment: @Ravi:If Employee were the *key* of the HashMap, you'd be seeing the hashCode method being called. See my edit above to see how HashMap calls hashCode and equals.

Comment: Thanks, I got understand, HashMap's key(class->hashCode) would be called.

Answer (score 3):

HashMap uses equals/hashCode of the Key value (in your case Integer).  I think that's what you are asking, right?

The reason why you have duplicates in your map, is you are using a new key for the same Employee.

```
  map.put(4, new Employee(4, "emp4", 345));
  map.put(5, new Employee(4, "emp4", 345));  // You are using 5 as the key
                                             // for the "same" object you did 
                                             // in the previous line
```

If you did something like

```
  // in main
  addEmployee(new Employee(4, "emp4", 345));
  addEmployee(new Employee(4, "emp4", 345));

  private void addEmployee(Employee e)
  {
     map.put(e.getId(), e);
  }
```

Then you would not see any duplicates in your collection.

Comment: i want to override hashCode and Equals but in HashMap 'Equals & hashCode' doen't override.
I want to apply it also on Value

Comment: @Ravi: this makes no sense. HashMap is working fine. You're just not understanding that the key is being checked.

Comment: Just want to confirm As just like HashSet calls equal and hashCode in this example, why hashMap is not being called even if for key.

Comment: eThe code you've provided _does_ call `equals` and `hashCode` for the keys, but the keys are `Integer`s, not `Employee`s.

Answer (score 3):

HashMap uses the keys as index, not the values.
(That is hashCode(), and maybe equals() gets called on the Integer class in your code above)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `HashMap<Integer, Employee>`, it looks like, so the `Integer`s will be hashed. Since the keys are `1,2,3,4,5`, the size of your `HashMap` should be 5.

Comment: but when you run it display size is 5